# Does Magic Pen also apply to singed's poison trail?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Magic Pen also apply to singed's poison trail? I still didn't test it, so if some of you know, it's going to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, since Singed's poison trail does magic damage, so it benefits from magic pen.

Comment: But you tested it?

Comment: Yes, it's just not often Singed builds Magic penetration beyond marks and the mastery because of how he is typically put into a tank role.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Teemo's, Cassiopeia's, and Singed's poison all do magic damage, so the more magic pen the more damage it will do.

Comment: But you tested it?